# Start Questetra process with values expressed by "Label" rather than by "Choice ID"

Tags: questetra

I can start a Questetra process like with this request:

```
curl https://sample.questetra.net/System/Event/IntermediateMessage/123/0/start \
   -d "data[0].selects=new_york"
```

... where the final parameter's value is the "Choice ID" in this table (called the `Master file of Choice type data item` in Questetra):

```
+-----------+----------+
| Choice ID | Label    |
+-----------+----------+
| new_york  | New York |
| paris     | Paris    |
| ...       | ...      |
+-----------+----------+
```

**Problem**: The client app only has data in the format of the `Label` column. For instance, the client app has `New York` but has no way to convert that to `new_york`.

**Question**: Is there any way to start the Questetra process using values from the `Label` column as arguments?

Either by specifying them directly and setting some kind of flag, or by getting the values "translated" using a preliminary request, or any other way.